# Motion Problem - Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An ant crawls along the sides of a 45-45-90 triangle. It starts at the right angle and crawls at a rate per minute of 50cm, 20cm, and 40cm, seperately, on each of the three sides, at what average speed does the ant crawl after it completely travels the three sides of the triangle?

I tried this problem, but I couldn't get the equation needed to solve the question.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Can you please [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem, explaining what you've tried and what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Ok. I added my thoughts.

Comment: what do you think the equation should have?

Comment: I'm not sure "I tried this problem, but I couldn't get the equation needed to solve the question." is what T.Bongers meant...

Comment: I need the correct equation needed to sovbe the problem

Comment: @Anonymous That really wasn't what I meant when I suggested that you add what you've tried. Your edit adds no new information to the question.

Comment: I couldn't try since I didn't know the equation.

Comment: I know 45 45 90 is x, x, and x radical 2, thats pretty much it

Comment: what do you suggest i do

Comment: Knowing that a 45,45,90 triangle has $x,x,x\sqrt{2}$ for sides seems like a pretty good place to start.

Comment: I know that, but I don't know how to get the hypotenuse

Comment: the only thing i need help with is hypotenuse

Comment: It will turn out that the value of $x$ is irrelevant. Draw a picture, The time taken on the first side is $\frac{x}{40}$. The time taken on the next is $\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{20}$. You can find the time taken for the third. Add up, you get total time. You also know total distance travelled. Now you can compute average speed.

Comment: It's those types of things that you should add to future problems asked. That way users can see precisely what details you're missing from continuing/solving.

Comment: (9x+10xrad2)/2?

Comment: hypotenuse is the biggest of all 3 sides, length of hypo.=sq.root(sum of squares of other 2 sides)

Comment: I still don't get it, I think I'm stupid...but I need help on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that that sides of the triangle are $x$ , $x$ and $x\sqrt{2}$.

The whole time it takes to travel three sides is :

$$\frac{x}{50}+\frac{x\sqrt{2}}{20}+\frac{x}{40}=\frac{(9+10\sqrt{2})x}{200}=\Delta t$$

The average speed is $\overline{V}=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{2x+x\sqrt{2}}{\Delta t}$ so 
$$\overline{V}=\frac{200(2+\sqrt{2})}{(9+10\sqrt{2})}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try to find the time, which the ant needs for each side. Then sum the times. After that you can divide the total distance by the total time.

Comment: 9 minutes average for two sides, I don't know how to do the hypotenuse